# iOS 9 Touch ID: LAErrorSystemCancel( -4) "Higher priority evaluation already running". Any ideas?

Tags: ios

I am working on iOS 9 Touch ID integration in a project and I am facing a situation where the error code (-4) is returned randomly.After that happens, Touch ID is not working(always returns -4 during Touch ID auth) until the application is restarted.

I tried replicating the same error in iOS 8, but I am not able to replicate it and I have never faced it iOS 8.

I would like to know if you have any pointers on this integration error.

Comment: This is happening for iPhone 6s in particular, anything changed on the iPhone 6s hardware?

Answer (score 0):

May be we need to sue Apple, they are closing issues saying it is duplicate of another issue and we can't see the other issue.

**Below is Apple update on this issue:**

*Engineering has determined that your bug report (24614069) is a duplicate of another issue (25088592) and will be closed.
The open or closed status of the original bug report your issue was duplicated to appears in the yellow "Duplicate of XXXXXXXX" section of the bug reporter user interface. This section appears near the top of the right column's bug detail view just under the bug number, title, state, product and rank.
An example of the duplicate section from the bug reporter user interface with your bug and the duplicate bug info is included below:
24614069 Error Code-->-4 during TouchID on iPhone 6s eventhough App is in foreground*

Comment: Did you find any answer/fix for that?